# How does an autoradio suppress transient, switching "plop" generated by an external audio source?

Tags: radio, automotive, transient-suppression

Out of curiosity I'd like to know how an autoradio device works. Maybe it' not how they *all* work and my case is just an exception but here it is.

I have a car TV tuner that is used to switch between its TV channel and an external source. Switching sources with the TV tuner produces a "plop" when the tuner is connected to a car amplifier. A a matter of fact, I have measured a DC component at the output of the tuner when it switches to the external source, which should not happen.

Out of curiosity, my colleague has connected the tuner's audio output (standard cinch plugs) to an autoradio. Strangely enough there's no more "plop" noise when the tuner switches between sources.

I didn't know autoradio devices could do that. There's no magic, I know. So I wonder how this one implements such a noise suppression. Is the input audio signal delayed so that a pre-processor can detect a potential DC component and suppress it shortly afterwards? Is it some kind of squelch control? Or is it something else?

Comment: It is probably a combination of one or more of those solutions. In a proper design there should be no DC voltage present on inputs, outputs and internally where the signal is switched. If a signal is switched inside one device it is possible to mute the output during switching as the device "knows" when the switching happens. Delaying the audio signal and detecting a plop is cumbersome, I would not expect that as that would be expensive.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This is the trick here: the car radio device does *not* know when a source is switched since the one that switches sources is before it and also happens to be the one that adds the DC component.

Comment: Then perhaps that car radio has an input resistor to ground which gets rid of the DC component. It is also possible that it has a high-pass filter or active DC compensation that filters out DC. Without seeing the schematics it is anyone's guess.

Comment: «*Without seeing the schematics it is anyone's guess*», well, true. I was hoping someone would happen to know if there are common practices in the automotive industry to achieve that.